# How to handle multiple items in RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, radio-button

I have four radio button inside the radio group in recyclerview. when i click first position of radio button it reflect on eighth position of radio button. How can i resolve this? If no radio button clicked the group will disable. how can i do this also? when i click the submit button calculate how many radio button clicked?

Xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:text="@string/question_1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_option_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="3" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_option_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="3" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_option_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="3" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_option_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="3" />

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Adapter :

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.RecyclerVH> {

private Context mCtx;
private List<TestResult> testList;

public TestAdapter(Context mCtx, List<TestResult> testList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.testList = testList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_test, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerVH(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerVH holder, final int position) {

    TestResult test = testList.get(position);

    String question = position + 1 + " " + test.getQuestion();
    holder.question.setText(question);
    holder.option_1.setText(test.getChoice0());
    holder.option_2.setText(test.getChoice1());
    holder.option_3.setText(test.getChoice2());
    holder.option_4.setText(test.getChoice3());

  // Log.d("Test",position+"");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return testList.size();
}

public void setList(ArrayList<TestResult> list) {
    this.testList = list;
}

class RecyclerVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView question;
    RadioButton option_1;
    RadioButton option_2;
    RadioButton option_3;
    RadioButton option_4;
    RadioGroup group;

    RecyclerVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        question = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_question);
        option_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_option_1);
        option_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_option_2);
        option_3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_option_3);
        option_4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_option_4);
        group = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your adapter, it will handle item according to respective position.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: @karthick-raja try this